# How to test NodeJS events in Jest

Tags: node.js, testing, events, jestjs

I have found several articles about testing events in the browser with Jest (usually relating to the DOM and components).

I am instead interested in testing NodeJS server-side events with Jest.

How would I go about this?

Example:

```
class MyClass extends EventEmitter
{
    aMethod()
    {
        this.emit("myEvent", data);
    }
}

// Jest:
it('should emit the event', () => {
    let c = new MyClass();
    c.aMethod();
    expect(.... the event is emitted .... how to do this? ....)
});
```

Comment: Substitute the original `.emit` with a Jest mock, and check if it was called

Comment: Doesn't that require modifying the original class?  Can you show me an example?

Comment: Your case is one example where "composition over inheritance" is definitely true. If instead `MyClass` would *refer* to an instance of `EventEmitter`, it would be fairly easy (if not trivial) to substitute it with another emitter with mocked `.emit()`. If you can refactor the code, that'd be the best approach.

Comment: Note in general, that NestJS doesn't play well with inheritance, even when it makes more sense than composition (judging from my own experience).